# How to add functionality on these Icons?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning the react using Material-UI. And I wanted to make a simple shopping app and here I'm stuck at this point.
I have a navbar but they are scattered. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Button, Box, TextField, MenuItem} from '@mui/material'
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import CallIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Call';
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorderOutlined';

import { useState } from 'react';

export const Navbar = () => {
    const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState<string[]>([])
    console.log(currencies)
    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = event.target.value
        setCurrencies(typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(','): value) 
    }

    const [languages, setLanguages] = useState<string[]>([])
    console.log(currencies)
    const HC = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = event.target.value
        setLanguages(typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(','): value) 
    }

  return (
    <>
     <Grid container my={2}> 
     <Grid item xs={5}>  
  
    <Box width={'200px'}> 
    <TextField 
    label='Select Currency' 
    select value={currencies} 
    onChange={handleChange} 
    fullWidth 
    SelectProps={{
        multiple: true
    }}
    size='small'
    >
        <MenuItem value='NP'> NEPAL </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='IN'> INDIA </MenuItem>
      
    </TextField>
     </Box>
  
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={5}>  
    <Box width={'200px'}> 
    <TextField 
    label='Select Language' 
    select value={languages} 
    onChange={HC} 
    fullWidth 
    SelectProps={{
        multiple: true
    }}
    size='small'

    >
        <MenuItem value='NP'> NEPAL </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='IN'> INDIA </MenuItem>
      
    </TextField>
     </Box>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={5}>  
    <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<CallIcon />}>
     CALL
    </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={5}>
    <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />}>
     Wishlist (0)
    </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={5}>
    ABOUT US
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={5}>
    CONTACT US
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={5}>
    <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<PersonIcon />}>
     Login
    </Button>
    </Grid>
   
    </Grid>
    
     </>
  )
}
```

now I have to

1. Put them on a single line ( two drop-down on very left and remaining on right side of the web page)
2. Add functionality on the icons, like When i click on call icon it should be called.
   ( I know how to add functionality on pages like about us (I simply add the next components to them)).
3. The wish list should be updated whenever i add items to wish list or remove them.

Comment: You can pass onClick props to these materil ui components, in material docs all props are mention in API section. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/icon-button/